# Virtualbox driver taking ~40 seconds to load at boot; can this be further diagnosed and maybe sped up?

Tags: boot, virtualbox

When my pc boots, (it is a vbox host), the top item in `systemd-analyze blame`'s output is

```
 38.229s vboxdrv.service
```

Which seems a bit excessive. Is there a way to further diagnose why it's so slow with an eye towards speeding it up?

System specs from `neofetch` here. Secure boot is disabled.

[image]

Comment: is Use host I/O caching enabled in VM settings (storage) for the disk? It is disabled by default now.

Comment: @Pilot6 this is the host. Thanks for the comment, will edit to point that out.